# Finding the smallest natural number given a value of a tau function (number of positive divisors)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the smallest $n\in N$ such that $\tau(n)=10$

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). To improve your post, you could copy-paste into it your answer below (and then delete it from there), and specify which of your step(s) you doubt. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification

Answer (score 1):

Let $n>1$ and $n=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}...p_r^{k_r}$ be the prime factorization of n such that $\tau(n)=10$. We know that $10=10\bullet1$
or $10=2\bullet5$. Then, we are certain that there are only two distinct prime factors of n where $k_1=0$ and $k_2=$, or $k_1=1$ and $k_2=4$. Since we want to find the smallest n with 10 positive divisors, it is logical to use the two lowest prime numbers 2 and 3. Thus, $n=2^03^9$ or $n=2^93^0$ or $n=2^13^4$ or $n=3^12^4$. Hence, n=19 683, or n=512, or n=162, or n=48.Therefore, by observation, 48 is the smallest natural number with 10 positive divisors.

Comment: "hen, we are certain that there are only two distinct prime factors of n where k1=0 and k2=, or k1=1 and k2=4. "  Why?  What do the powers of the prime factorization of $n$ have to do with the $\tau$ function?  Do you know some formula of figuring the value of $\tau(n)$ via the prime factorization of $n$? It sounds like you do but you aren't sharing it.   If you know some such formula [maybe $\tau(n)= \prod (k_i+1)$???] you ought include it in your write up.

Comment: Dont worry about $k_i = 0$.  $p^0 =1$ and one is the multiplicative identity that is always there.  Either we have $n = p_1^9$ or $n=p_1^1p_2^4$.  Also if we can claim it is logical to use the smallest primes we can also claim we should use the smallest primes for the highest power.  We don't have to consider $3^4\times 2^1$ as $3^{low}2^{high}< 3^{high}2^{low}$.  And we *certainly* don't need to consider $2^0\times 3^9 = 3^9$ as $3^9 > 2^9$.  So our only concerns are whether $2^9$ is more or less than $2^4\times 3^1$.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections and insights. We were tasked to post our answers here so we can get further knowledge about this. I did not think about claiming to use the smallest primes for the highest power either. Thanks a lot

Comment: FYI.... sometimes it is useful to consider instead of  the prime factorization being the finest list of primes $p_1^{k_1}..... p_r^{k_r}; k_i \ge 1$ to consider an infinite list $n = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} p_i^{k_i}$ where $p_1=2, p_2= 3, p_3=5$ etc.  And an infinite number of the $k_i$ are all equal to $0$. (so for example the prime factorization of $55= 2^0\cdot 3^0\cdot 5^1\cdot 7^0 \cdot 11^1 \cdot 13^0.....$.  This way you won't be tempted to say $10\cdot 1=10$ so we have $p_1^0p_2^{9}$ when $p_1^0 = 1$ and doesn't bear consideration....

Comment: It's very good that you tried everything.  It's better to try too much than too little.  If one doesn't feel confident saying *obviously* $3^4 \times 2^1 > 2^4 \times 3^1$ it's better that you show both.  But if you do feel confident saying higher bases to higher powers are more than lower bases to the same powers... well, you can.